# Use Maclaurin series of a function to determine another

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

The prompt is to determine Maclaurin series of the function $f(x) = -x^5ln(1-2x^3)$ using the Maclaurin series for $g(x) = ln(x+1)$ also to find for what value of x the series f(x) converges, and hence evaluate $f^{100}(0)$ and $f^{101}(0)$.

Here's what I tried,
$$g(x) = ln(1+x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}x^n$$
$$f(x) =-x^5ln(1 + (-2x^3)) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^5)(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}(-2x)^{3n}$$

Using ratio test on f(x)
$$a_n = \frac{(-x^5)(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}(-2x)^{3n}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(-x^5)(-1)^{n + 1}(-1)}{n + 1}(-2x)^{3n}(-2x^3)$$

Applying limits and cancelling terms on numerator and denominator,

$$|2x^3|\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1}$$

$$|2x^3| < 1$$
$$\frac{-1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}$$

To check the border values to find the interval of convergence,
$$f(x) =-x^5ln(1 + (-2x^3)) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^5)(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}(-2x)^{3n}$$

$$f(\frac{-1}{2})  = \frac{(\frac{-1}{2})^5(-1)^{n + 1}(-2)(\frac{-1}{2})^{3n}}{n} = \frac{-2}{n}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{-1}{n} = 0$$

This means f(x) converges at $\frac{-1}{2}$
Testing $f(\frac{1}{2})$ now,

$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^5(-1^{n + 1})(-2 \frac{-1}{2})^{3n}}{n} = \frac{(-2)(-1)^{3n}}{n}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-2)}{n} = 0$$
Hence, series converges at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ as well, 
Interval of convergence is $[\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$

Finding the n-th derivatives using the series,
$$ f^{100}(0)  = \frac{-(0)^5(-1)^{n+1}}{100}.(-2)(0)^{300} = 0$$
$$ f^{101}(0)  = \frac{-(0)^5(-1)^{n+1}}{101}.(-2)(0)^{303} = 0$$

Comment: Check your calculation for $f(x)$; you forget to raise the factor $(-2)$ to the power $n$. That is: $\ln(1-2x^{3})=\ln(1+u)$ where $u=-2x^{3}$ and so $\ln(1+u)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}u^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(-2x^{3})^{n}$..... you take it from there!

Comment: If you edit your post with the correction stated above, we can then discuss the interval of convergence and the $n^{\text{th}}$-derivatives.

Comment: Done making changes

Comment: Looking better. Check your calculation for convergence: you forgot to take cube roots in the last step! For the interval of convergence, but the values of $x$ into the series itself and check if this series converges, using an appropriate test. We can get to the derivatives after those are straight.